# Steam doesn't open on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, games, gnome-terminal, steam

Steam does not open at all when i open it from search, and in the terminal it says

```
Repairing installation, linking /home/xyz/.steam/steam to /home/xyz/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
/home/xyz/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_send_request_with_fds
/home/xyz/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 444: no match: ssfn*
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can work around this problem by opening a terminal and running

```
~/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam
```

After it completes, press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and search for `steam`, launching the application like normal.

That might do another round of updates, and finally, the steam login window should now be displayed and it seems to work like normal.

Comment: Almost. I did as you said, but I had to run 'steam' after. Then it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Is this problem already reported and if not, where would be the best place to do it? (I used the deb-package from the steam website)

Comment: I guess it would be here https://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/

Comment: For the record: 4 months later this bug is still unpatched and you answer helped me get around it :)

Comment: Hmmm, tried running that , but still getting the error when running, and doesn't launch from Super window.

Comment: Correction - running apt-get update, apt-get full-update, then this from home did work after.  Thanks!

Comment: folder "~/.local/share/Steam" does not exist in my system. How can I fix that?