# Can't run Steam in Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: steam

When I open Steam nothing happens but running `steam` from the terminal it shows

```
Repairing installation, linking /home/username/.steam/steam to /home/username/.local/share/Steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
/home/username/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam: symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-dri3.so.0: undefined symbol: xcb_send_request_with_fds
/home/username/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: Line 444: no match: ssfn*
```

Comment: Before anything else make sure your system is fully updated: Run `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt full-upgrade`. Also [edit] and update your question accordingly with any error messages and/or new or additional informations.

Comment: Might be a locale issue, try setting `LC_ALL=C` before running steam. i.e. `LC_ALL=C steam`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Steam doesn open on ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966373/steam-doesn-open-on-ubuntu-17-10)